# getting XmlSearch to return siblings only, not children

Tags: xpath, coldfusion

I'm getting a SOAP response that looks like this:

```
<Activity>
    <Id>A</Id>
    <Subject>foo</Subject>
    <Activity>Task</Activity>
</Activity>
<Activity>
    <Id>B</Id>
    <Subject>bar</Subject>
    <Activity>Appointment</Activity>
</Activity>
<Activity>
    <Id>C</Id>
    <Subject>snafu</Subject>
    <Activity>Task</Activity>
</Activity>
```

In Coldfusion, I was trying to parse out the Activity nodes with this:

```
<cfset arrMainNodes = XmlSearch(soapResponse,  "//*[name()='Activity']")  />
```

The problem is, instead if getting an array with three elements, I get an array with six: 3 of the parent, and 3 of the children.

I can't for the life of me figure out the XPath statement the will find siblings only, and not children.

Please Help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Use**:

```
//*[name()='Activity' and not(ancestor::*[name()='Activity' ])]
```

**This selects all elements in the document, whose name is `"Activity"` and that do not have an ancestor with name `"Activity"`**.

Comment: I could be wrong, but I do not think he is trying to exclude ones with a child named `Activity`. But grab the parent `Activity` elements instead of the child ie `<Activity>Task</Activity>`

Comment: or, "simplifying" :) things, maybe just a simple `/*/Activity`?

Comment: @PavelVeller: The OP provided a *fragment* and it is no way guaranteed to be "fathered" by the top element in the XML document. Guessing is meaningless.

Comment: @DimitreNovatchev, fair enough. `//Activity[not(ancestor::Activity)]`. is there a difference between `Activity` and `*[name() = 'Activity']` other than the length of the expression?

Comment: @DimitreNovatchev - Cool. Looks like that would do it.

Comment: @PavelVeller: Yes, for some XML documents the first expression doesn't select a node, while the second does. A SOAP response can be of the second type.

Comment: Awesome, Dimitre. That did the trick.  Thanks, I learned something.